# "The missing ingredient in your recipe" or "The ingredient missing in your recipe"?

Tags: word-order

I'm currently creating a slogan for a company and I'm struggling to decide on how to formulate it.

I would really appreciate some feedback as to which option sounds more "natural" and is grammatically correct (sample sentence below):

> Cinnamon : the **missing ingredient** in your recipe.

or

> Cinnamon : the **ingredient missing** in your recipe.

Comment: The first phrase is more natural

Comment: What about: "The ingredient you need in your recipe!"

Answer (score 1):

The first is more natural but it implies to some extent that the recipe has (or is meant to have) cinnamon as an ingredient. The second seems more like a radical idea.